# Updating jsonb column in one table based on a column in second table using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table named `clubs` and these are some of the relevant columns in this table:

```
COLUMN_NAME     DATA_TYPE  IS_NULLABLE  
id              uuid       NO
general_fields  jsonb      YES
```

and I have another table named `plans` and these are some of the relevant columns in this table:

```
COLUMN_NAME                 DATA_TYPE  IS_NULLABLE  
id                          uuid       NO
club_id                     uuid       NO
hide_in_online_application  bool       YES
```

A club can have multiple plans.

I want to write a query that updates the boolean type `allow_applications` as **FALSE** inside the column general_fields for those clubs in the `clubs` table that only have plans where `hide_in_online_application` is **TRUE**

The query will have something like:

```
UPDATE clubs
SET general_fields = jsonb_set(general_fields, '{allow_applications}', '"false"')
+ the condition where clubs has no plans
+ the condition where all plans from clubs are hide_in_online_application == true
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE clubs
SET general_fields = jsonb_set(general_fields, '{allow_applications}', '"false"')
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM plans WHERE clubs.id = plans.club_id AND plans.hide_in_online_application = true)
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM plans WHERE clubs.id = plans.club_id AND plans.hide_in_online_application = false)
```

Comment: It will change the allow_applications to false if a club has at least 1 plan hide_in_online_application = true.  
However, I need this to happen only for clubs that only have plan(s) with hide_in_online_application = false and have no other plans apart from this. (irrespective of hide_in_online_application)